# Using ternary operators in Q objects and avoid query with None values

Tags: python, django

While chaining Q objects in django, how can I avoid using a Q object if a particular value is None?

I wrote the following:

```
print("Doing an AND search")
SearchResult = customer.objects.filter(
    Q(cstid=HospitalID if HospitalID else None) &
    Q(insurance_number__lower__contains=insurance_number.lower() if insurance_number else None) &
    Q(name__lower__contains=name.lower() if name else None) &
    Q(ageyrs=ageyrs if ageyrs.isdigit() else None) &
    Q(agemnths=agemnths if agemnths.isdigit() else None) &
    Q(mobile__contains=mobile if mobile else None) &
    Q(alternate__contains=alternate if alternate else None) &
    Q(email__lower__contains=email.lower() if email else None) &
    Q(address__lower__contains=address.lower() if address else None) &
    Q(city__lower__contains=city.lower() if city else None) 
,linkedclinic=clinicobj)
SearchResult = customer.objects.filter(my_q, linkedclinic=clinicobj)
```

I get the error:

```
POST data <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['YN6riYcjKaYUi6wtwPCY6AzqPt8JwL5VZiZKo0y8r4zBlBBv4ncpWLvubclroSVE'], 'HospitalID': [''], 'insurance_number': [''], 'name': [''], 'ageyrs': [''], 'agemnths': [''], 'email': ['rie'], 'mobile': [''], 'alternate': [''], 'address': [''], 'city': [''], 'include_all_terms': ['on']}>
Doing an AND search
2019-08-11 01:04:33,826 django.request ERROR    Internal Server Error: /clinic/checkin
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/joel/myappointments/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
File "/home/joel/myappointments/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "/home/joel/myappointments/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/joel/myappointments/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/joel/myappointments/clinic/views.py", line 2840, in checkin_patient_specific
    ORSearchResult = ORSearch_Patients(HospitalID, clinicobj, name, ageyrs, agemnths, mobile, alternate, email, address, city, insurance_number=insurance_number, include_all=include_all)
File "/home/joel/myappointments/clinic/views.py", line 651, in ORSearch_Patients
    Q(city__lower__contains=city.lower() if city else None) , linkedclinic=clinicobj)
File "/home/joel/myappointments/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/joel/myappointments/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 892, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/joel/myappointments/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 910, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
File "/home/joel/myappointments/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1290, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
File "/home/joel/myappointments/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1312, in _add_q
    current_negated, allow_joins, split_subq, simple_col)
File "/home/joel/myappointments/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1318, in _add_q
    split_subq=split_subq, simple_col=simple_col,
File "/home/joel/myappointments/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1251, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
File "/home/joel/myappointments/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1121, in build_lookup
    raise ValueError("Cannot use None as a query value")
ValueError: Cannot use None as a query value
```

Answer (score 2):

We can here define a function that uses dictionary comprehension that ignores key-value items if the value is `None` like:

```
def q_if_not_none(**kwargs):
    return Q(**{k: v for k, v in kwargs.items() if v is not None})
```

We can then use the `q_if_not_none` function to create a `Q` object that ignores all `None`s:

```
SearchResult = customer.objects.filter(q_if_not_none(
    cstid=HospitalID,
    insurance_number__icontains=insurance_number,
    name__icontains=name,
    ageyrs=ageyrs if ageyrs.isdigit() else None,
    agemnths=agemnths if agemnths.isdigit() else None,
    mobile__icontains=mobile,
    alternate__icontains=alternate,
    email__icontains=email,
    address__icontains=address,
    city__icontains=city,
), linkedclinic=clinicobj)
```

Note that you better use the [**`__icontains`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#icontains) lookup than converting to lowercase. It is a very common misconception that case-insensitive comparisons can be done by converting both operands to lowercase (or uppercase). Some languages, like German, have characters (for example the [*eszett ß* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F)) that have *no* lowercase equivalent, or with special rules for comparisons. In Python, you use [**`str.casefold`** [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.casefold) for case insensitive comparisons.

Comment: I faced a mysql specific problem while using icontains. That's why I had to make do with the lowercase conversion.

Comment: @JoelGMathew: that is likely due some misconfigured collation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-general.html But anyway, even if you here use a different expression, `q_if_not_none` should ignore the ones with `None` as value.